# set default page for click function to load external page

Tags: php, jquery, html

am using `jquery` to load external page inside `div` that works great 
but only when i trigger click function it opens a external page

when page is loaded it should trigger first button

tried this

```
function HideLoader() {
                    $('#loader').css('display', 'none');
                }

                function ShowLoader() {
                    $('#loader').css('display', 'block');
                }


                $('.reveal').on('click', function (e) {
                    var $that = $(this);
                    e.preventDefault();
                    ShowLoader();
                    var link = $(this).attr('href');
                    $('.tab-content').load(link, function () {
                        HideLoader(); // this puts it in the load callback, so that this stuff
                        $that.show(); // happens when the load is complete
                    });
                });
```

### HTML

```
<div class="btn-pref btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary reveal" href="test.php">
                            <div class="hidden-xs">Info</div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default reveal" href="#tab2">
                            <div class="hidden-xs">Favorites</div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default reveal" href="#tab3">
                            <div class="hidden-xs">Following</div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default reveal" href="#tab3">
                            <div class="hidden-xs">Friends</div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
 <div class="well">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <img src="../css/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" class="center" id="loader"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

this function is in `index.php` when i run this file it should display `test.php` and when i go for `click function()` function should continue..

i tried above method but doesn't works

Comment: Just as a side note, you could use the load function instead of the get. Load will do the AJAX call and set the content of the target element to the html returned by the AJAX. see : http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: why not place your `.get()` function outside of the `click()` ?

Comment: Please explain *"doesn't works"*. What do you mean with *when I go for `click function()`*? Is the HTML you have provided `test.php`? Do I understand correctly that you want the first button to be clicked automatically when the page loads (so that first tab content will be loaded)?

Comment: when i open page it should trigger first button the `test.php` by default without clicking

Comment: @trincot yes `Do I understand correctly that you want the first button to be clicked automatically when the page loads (so that first tab content will be loaded)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can automate a click of the first button on page load as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $('.btn-primary').click();
});
```

The docs on the [`click` method](https://api.jquery.com/click/) have:

> Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

In the above code, it is the triggering that we're doing.

About [$(function ...)](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.
>
> Experienced developers sometimes use the shorthand `$()`

If that does not do anything, the second option is to wait for the page to have loaded completely (also images, etc.):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.btn-primary').click();
});
```

About [`$(window).load`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

> Run a function when the page is fully loaded including graphics.

Answer (score 1):

First put id on your first button

```
<button type="button" id="first_btn" class="btn btn-primary reveal" href="test.php">
```

Then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#first_btn").click();
});
```

Run and check if you get the result.